# Changing icons font color in Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: colors, icons, desktop, linux-mint

I recently set a black desktop background and I installed the ambiance-colors in LM 17.1. The font color of the icons in the desktop is grey, and I can't read the names of the folders! I searched an option to change the color, but I didn't find it. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.